# Оптимизация GUI

Tags: python, gui, pyqt5

есть одно приложение на PyQt5.

```
try:
    i = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./bin"):
        for name in dirs:
            self.jobName = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.jobName.setText(name)
            self.jobName.setObjectName("job_"+str(i+1))          
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.jobName, i, 0, i, 0)
            i+=1
            self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.but.setObjectName("jobButt_"+str(i))
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but, i, 1, i, 1)
            i+=1
            self.but.setText("Запустить")
            self.but.clicked.connect(self.launch)
            print(str(name))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Этот кусок кода ищет папки и выводит в скролл бар, ну тоесть должен выводить в скролл бар. В итоге выходит что то подобное:
[image: Это при запуске]

[image: Это при нажатии на кнопку Обновить]

К скролл бару прикрепляется только первое(что неправильно) по алфавиту(что правильно), как мне оптимизировать процесс обновления?

UPD
Это в принципе всё

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import mainDes, os, sys, subprocess

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mainDes.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.refresh.clicked.connect(self.refr)
        self.createShoto.clicked.connect(self.launch)

    def refr(self):
        try:
            i = 0
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./bin"):
                for name in dirs:
                    self.jobName = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
                    self.jobName.setText(name)
                    self.jobName.setObjectName("job_"+str(i+1))
                    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.jobName, i, 0, i, 0)
                    i+=1
                    self.aga = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
                    self.aga.setObjectName("jobButt_"+str(i))
                    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.aga, i, 1, i, 1)
                    i+=1
                    self.aga.setText("Запустить")
                    self.aga.clicked.connect(self.launch)
                    print(str(name))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Можете ли вы опубликовать минимально-полный код для лучшего понимания проблемы?

Comment: @S. Nick добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как бы и не все )
Модуль `mainDes` остался за бортом.

Попробовал заменит атрибуты и методы, содержащиеся в модуле `mainDes`, в самом  `Main`.
В чем у вас проблема понять не могу.

Попробуйте пример ниже, может у вас появятся новые идеи.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
#import mainDes                                    #                           ---

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):                 #, mainDes.Ui_MainWindow):  ---
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #self.setupUi(self)                         #                          ---
        # заменитель атрибутов и методов содержащихся в модуле `mainDes`
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.layoutV       = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = "self.scrollAreaWidgetContents"
        self.gridLayout    = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.refresh       = QtWidgets.QPushButton("refresh",     self.centralWidget)
        self.createShoto   = QtWidgets.QPushButton("createShoto", self.centralWidget)
        self.layoutV.addWidget(self.refresh)
        self.layoutV.addWidget(self.createShoto)
        self.layoutV.addLayout(self.gridLayout)

        self.refresh.clicked.connect(self.refr)
        self.createShoto.clicked.connect(self.launch)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                            # +++

    def refr(self):
        try:
            i = 0

            #           установите свой путь  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  !!!
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk("E:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Test/bin"):

                for name in dirs:
                    self.jobName = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
                    self.jobName.setText(name)
                    self.jobName.setObjectName("job_"+str(i+1))
                    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.jobName, i, 0)        #, i, 0) ---
                    #i+=1                                                #        ---
                    self.aga = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
                    self.aga.setObjectName("jobButt_"+str(i))
                    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.aga, i, 1)            #, i, 1) ---
                    i+=1
                    self.aga.setText("Запустить")
                    self.aga.clicked.connect(self.launch)
                    print("dirName ->", str(name))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    # +++ 
    def launch(self):  
        sender = self.sender()
        print("def launch(self): text=`{}`, objectName=`{}`"
              "".format(sender.text(), sender.objectName()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Действительно появились новые идеи, спасибо